# Call Ajax or submit the button when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have following PHP while loop which is showing data as the checkbox. The checkbox can be multiple or one.

```
<?php
$supplier = new Admin;
$supplier->rowQuery("SELECT * FROM supplier");

echo '<form id="formId">';
    while ( $data = $supplier->result->fetch_assoc()) {        

        $sid          =  (int) $data['sid'];
        $supplierName = output($data['supplierName']);

        echo '<label class="checkbox-inline">';
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sid[]' data-sid='$sid' value='$sid' class='supplierClass'> $supplierName";
        echo '</label>';
    }
echo '<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="supplier" class="clickBtn">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Now I want to call Ajax when at least one checkbox or multiple checkbox is checked. So to do that I have following Javascrpt:

```
$('.supplierClass').click(function() {
var sid = $(this).data('sid');
if(this.checked){
   // $("input[type=submit]").trigger(".clickBtn");
   $('.clickBtn').trigger();
   $('#formId').submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url         :   'process/get-vehicle.php',
        type        :   'POST',
        dataType    :   'html',
        data        :   {
          sid   :  sid,
        },
        beforeSend  :   function () {
            $('.allVehicle').html('Please wait...');
        },
        success     :   function ( result ) {
            $('.allVehicle').html(result);
        }
    });
  });
}
});
```

but it's not called the Ajax :(

**Overall Goal**

You can see that I have set the checkbox name as `array` sid[]. Becuase I need to get all checkbox checked data as array in a PHP file.

So how can I call Ajax when one or multiple checkboxes are checked? **Please note that: In PHP file I want to get all checkbox or one checkbox value.**

**My Thought:**

I think there should be a submit button as hidden. When I click on any checkbox It's should press the hidden button by jQuery to call the Ajax.

Comment: `clickBtn` is type `hidden`? Also, I don't recommend binding the form submit event inside the click handler for the checkboxes

Comment: You don't need any submit button, just trigger the AJAX request when a checkbox is checked and submit the serialize form as data.

Comment: @hungrykoala let me try it.

Comment: @hungrykoala do you mean this serialize: `data        :    $('#formId').serialize(),`

Comment: Yes, that will get all the data available for that form

Comment: remove $('#formId').submit(function() {, call ajax $.ajax({ });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the submit event, use a change event, get all the checked sids

```
$('.supplierClass').change(function() {

if( $('.supplierClass:checked').length){
 var sids = [];
 $('.supplierClass:checked').each(function(i,v) {//get all the sids of the elements checked
     sids.push($(v).val());
  });
      $.ajax({
        url         :   'process/get-vehicle.php',
        type        :   'POST',
        dataType    :   'html',
        data        :   {
          sid   :  sids,
        },
        beforeSend  :   function () {
            $('.allVehicle').html('Please wait...');
        },
        success     :   function ( result ) {
            $('.allVehicle').html(result);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: This is working BUT in PHP I can get only 1 sid value. I need to get all sid value. I mean If checked all checkbox then I should get all checkbox data.

Comment: Great now I can get all the checkbox value as a multidimensional array. Is it possible without a multidimensional array?

Comment: why is it called  multidimensional array? to store multiple values?you don't know how to loop in php?

Comment: you can create a key/value pair for each checked element if you want

Comment: something like `var sids = {};
 $('.supplierClass:checked').each(function(i,v) {
     sids['element'+i] = $(v).val());
  });`

Comment: sorry, I mean I get all the data as a multidimensional array. Is it possible without a multidimensional array?

Comment: can you paste the output of your data and the desired output format?

Comment: now the data is showing like that in php  file: `Array
(
    [sid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )

)`

Comment: what is the name of the first array? Second array name is sid but what is  the name of the first array?

Comment: do something like `var_dump($_POST['sid']);` and you should have the inner array

Comment: My hero of the day :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for submit button in order to do ajax request. I have altered your code. Hope this one suits your requirement.

```
$('.supplierClass').change(function () {
   var sid = $(this).data('sid');
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'process/get-vehicle.php',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'html',
         data: {
            sid: sid,
         },
         beforeSend: function () {
            $('.allVehicle').html('Please wait...');
         },
         success: function (result) {
             $('.allVehicle').html(result);
         }
      });
  }
 });
```

I have triggered ajax call on the check box change event and only on the when its checked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("click", '.supplierClass:checked', function() {
  var sid = $(this).val() // gets the sid 
  alert('clicked checkbox => ' + sid); // checking if this code gets called
  $.ajax({
    url: 'process/get-vehicle.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      sid: sid,
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      //Code Goes here
    },
    success: function(result) {
      //code goes here
    },
    error: function(err) {
      //code goes here
    }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Check Box</p>

  <input type='checkbox' name='sid[]' data-sid='$sid' value='1' class='supplierClass'>
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sid[]' data-sid='$sid' value='2' class='supplierClass'>
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sid[]' data-sid='$sid' value='3' class='supplierClass'>
  <br>
</div>
```

This code runs only when the checkbox gets checked and sends one checkbox value to PHP server , you don't need a hidden submit button to do this